# checking heap consistency with mcheck

Tags: c, malloc, heap-memory, heap-corruption

I am looking for a way to check for heap corruption periodically.
(My system under test cannot run valgrind or any other similar tool)

I am trying to find out why this code does not work:

```
int main() {

    if (mcheck(NULL) != 0) {

        fprintf(stderr, "mcheck() failed\n");

        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while (1) {
        usleep(1);
        char *a = (char *)malloc(726);

        /* touching the block to own it */
        a[5] = 12;

        free(a);
        /* write after free */
        memset(a, 0xBD, 726);

        /* this should go wild ! */
        mcheck_check_all();
    }
}
```

**Double free** actually does the trick and i get a call to abort but not with using the memory after it was freed (which should cause heap corruption because of meta data used by malloc

Comment: @EugeneSh.- please explain... also, with GDB i am able to get to this call and still nothing happens... also with double free, even without mcheck_check_all - i get a call to abort

Comment: As far as I understand, `mcheck` won't prevent the writing unallocated memory from being UB, so `memset` will just do bad things.

Comment: Your program is written in such a way that `mcheck` will not detect an error. Because you are setting only the data area and there are no other allocations after the free. Try this: after the `free(a)` and before the `memset`, add `char *b = malloc(100);`. That should be enough to corrupt the allocator control blocks and will be detected by `mcheck_check_all`.

Comment: @kaylum, why didn't you post your explanation as answer?

Comment: @red0ct Because I feel a proper answer would need more explanation than I have given on why mcheck does not detect that type of error. And also explain why my proposed change would make it detect. I don't have time to do that now but still wanted to point the OP in the right direction. I may add an answer later if I have time. But anyone else (including yourself) is welcome to expand that comment into a proper answer - I won't mind.